# Rails can't find my route but it exists!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-routes

Ok I have events that I want to publish/unpublish with an extra action (nonRESTful) I watched Ryan Bates' railscast on this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/35-custom-rest-actions and it got me most of the way. I think the problem is that my route is nested in an `/admin` section so even though when I run `rake routes` and get:

```
publish_admin_event PUT /admin/events/:id/publish(.:format) {:controller=>"event_services", :action=>"publish"}
```

This won't work in my /views/admin/index.html.erb file:

```
<%= link_to 'Publish', publish_admin_event(event), :method => :put %>
```

because it claims that path doesn't exist! And neither will this:

```
<%= link_to 'Publish', {:controller => :event_services, :action => :publish}, {:method => :put, :id => event} %>
```

and says that "`No route matches {:controller=>"event_services", :action=>"publish"}`"

so what gives? (And I've tried restarting my server so that isn't it.)

**EDIT:**
This DOES work:

```
<%= link_to 'Publish', "/admin/events/" + event.id.to_s + "/publish", :method => :put %>
```

But I'd rather NOT do this.

**EDIT #2:**
My route entry:

```
map.resource :admin do |admin|
  admin.admin '', :controller => :admin, :only => :index
  admin.resources :events, :controller => :event_services, :member => {:publish => :put } do |service_event|
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your route entry?

Comment: @Andy Gaskell: posted but I will probably accept sepp2k's answer. If you have anything useful to add as an answer though, I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This won't work in my /views/admin/index.html.erb file:
>
> ```
> <%= link_to 'Publish', publish_admin_event(event), :method => :put %>
> ```
>
> because it claims that path doesn't exist!

I'd rather expect it not to work because of a NoMethodError. I think you meant to write `publish_admin_event_path` instead of just `publish_admin_event` there. Then it should work.

> And neither will this:
>
> ```
> <%= link_to 'Publish', {:controller => :event_services, :action => :publish}, {:method => :put, :id => event} %>
> ```

This will work if you do `:controller => "/admin/event_services"` (though that isn't necessary if you're already in the admin namespace) and, as you figured out in your comment, move `:id => event` into the first hash.

Comment: That first part worked! I don't know what I forgot the `_path` part! The second part doesn't work. See my second edit.

Comment: ok the second works if i leave :controller => :event_services and put my :id => event into the first hash.

Comment: @DJTripleThreat: Oops, I didn't see that. Yes, event_services will work if you're already in the admin namespace. `admin/event_services` will work when you're in the top-level namespace. And `/admin/event_services` will work no matter where you are.